# Bad Request 400 -@RequestBody

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I am trying to send JSON :

```
{"source": "CED:100973626887874,CED:77148046400112,CED:222222222222201"}`
```

and my Controller is as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/multipleMember/list", method =RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<MemberDetail> getMultipleMemberList(
        @RequestBody String memberList) {
    return memberServiceDelegate.getMultipleMemberList(memberList);
}
```

But I am getting bad request 400 : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps your json object will need an object named memberList

```
{"memberList": "CED:100973626887874,CED:77148046400112,CED:222222222222201"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to wrap your json with { } in order to indicate it is an object.

```
{
"source": "CED:100973626887874,CED:77148046400112,CED:222222222222201" 
}
```

Comment: Also, is "CED:100973626887874,CED:77148046400112,CED:222222222222201" the value of source? or are you aiming for that to be JSON as well?