# how to solve 400 (Bad Request) error with ajax and codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting a 400 (Bad Request) error with ajax and codeigniter

this is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>query/sensor/'+ test + / + past  + / + id + / + port + / + device,

            success: function(res) {
            if (res)
            {

                console.log("res"+res);
                    }
            }
            });


      }
```

is it a proper ajax url?

Comment: i don't like how you're not concatenating strings after `+ test +`

Comment: ok how to pass multiple parameters via ajax?

Comment: See the URL getting requested in `network` tab of `inspect element`.

Comment: yes it gives me a console error

Comment: its look like this 
jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:81/test1/query/sensor/ABC/%20+%20past%20+%20/9/%20+%20id%20+%20/1 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: use   url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>query/sensor/'+ test +' / '+ past  + '/' + id + '/' + 'port' + '/' + device,

Comment: it worked but now it gives me a 403 (Forbidden) error anyone familiar with this error?

Comment: @jowy make sure the route accepts post requests

Comment: In POST type use GET instead of POST ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad Request 400 -@RequestBody](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019806/bad-request-400-requestbody)

Answer (score 0):

- First Make sure you get variables values test, past ....
- You can change
  url: 'query/sensor/'+ test + / + past  + / + id + / + port + / + device,

  With this url:

url: 'query/sensor/'+ test +'/' + past  + '/' + id + '/' + port + '/' + device,

regards :)

Comment: _italic_ Good Luke

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(
"your_url", 
{
  value1: value1,
  value2: value2,
  value3: value3,

}, 
function(result){

  alert(result);
});
```

Use this post method